# How to get all rows from a table inserted in a particular date.

Tags: sql, db2, h2

I am trying to write a query that gets all the rows of a table for a particular date.

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE COLUMN_CONTAINING_DATE='2013-05-07'
```

However that does not work, because in the table the COLUMN_CONTAINING_DATE contains data like '2013-05-07 00:00:01' etc. So, this would work

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE COLUMN_CONTAINING_DATE>='2013-05-07' AND COLUMN_CONTAINING_DATE<'2013-05-08'
```

However, I dont want to go for option 2 because that feels like a hacky way. I would rather put a query that says get me all the rows for a give date and somehow not bother about the minutes and hours in the COLUMN_CONTAINING_DATE.

I am trying to have this query run on both H2 and DB2.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It should be noted that option #2 is SARG-able and will perform better than using a function in the Where clause.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
select *
from MY_Table
where trunc(COLUMN_CONTAINING_DATE) = '2013-05-07';
```

However, the version that you describe as a "hack" is actually better.  By wrapping a function around the data, many SQL optimizers will not use indexes.  With just direct comparisons, an index would definitely be used.

Comment: Just ran that on H2 and got > "Function "TRUNC" not found; SQL statement:"

Comment: @partha . . . Stick with your "hack" version.  Experienced SQLers know it is the best approach because of the use of the index.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE COLUMN_CONTAINING_DATE=DATE('2013-05-07')
```

Comment: Um, no.  If (as it appears to be) `COLUMN_CONTAINING_DATE` is a timestamp type, the result of calling `DATE('2013-05-07')` will be auto-converted to a timestamp, as well (resulting in `'2013-05-07 00:00:00.000000'`) - the reason is so that the engine won't have to convert every row in the table to get results!

Answer (score 0):

You can ease this if you use the Temporal data management capability from DB2 10.1.

For more information:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1204db2temporaldata/

Answer (score 0):

If your concerns are related to the different data types (timestamp in the column, and a string containing a date), you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
  WHERE 
        COLUMN_CONTAINING_DATE >= '2013-05-07 00:00:00' 
    and COLUMN_CONTAINING_DATE <  '2013-05-08 00:00:00'
```

and I'd pay attention to the formatting of the where clause, because this will improve readability a lot, if you have to look at your queries two months later. Just pick a style you prefer for ranges like "a <= x < b". Unfortunately SQL's *between* does not support this.

One could argue that the milliseconds are still missing, so perfectionists may append another ".0" in the timestamp ...